# Trying to install Ora2pg

Tags: rhel, oracle

I am on an Amazon EC2 server running RHEL. The version is:

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.3 (Ootpa)"
```

I am trying to [install Ora2pg](https://ora2pg.darold.net/documentation.html#Installing-Ora2Pg) (it is based on Perl). But I'm getting stuck on the first few instructions, specifically the `make && make install`.

I get the following:

```
[oracle@ip-10-0-26-247 ora2pg-21.1]$ perl Makefile.PL
Invalid LICENSE value 'GPLv3' ignored
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Ora2Pg
Invalid LICENSE value 'GPLv3' ignored
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

Done...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Please read documentation at http://ora2pg.darold.net/ before asking for help
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Now type: make && make install
[oracle@ip-10-0-26-247 ora2pg-21.1]$ sudo make && make install
[sudo] password for oracle:
Skip blib/lib/Ora2Pg/GEOM.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/Ora2Pg/PLSQL.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/Ora2Pg.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/Ora2Pg/MySQL.pm (unchanged)
cp scripts/ora2pg blib/script/ora2pg
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/ora2pg
cp scripts/ora2pg_scanner blib/script/ora2pg_scanner
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/ora2pg_scanner
Manifying 1 pod document
Manifying 1 pod document
Installing default configuration file (ora2pg.conf.dist) to /etc/ora2pg
mkdir /etc/ora2pg: Permission denied at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/ExtUtils/Command.pm line 299.
make: *** [Makefile:931: install_all] Error 255
[oracle@ip-10-0-26-247 ora2pg-21.1]$
```

I get a `Permission denied` error even though I'm running as `sudo`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I needed `sudo make && sudo make install` to get it to work.